# Pushing items to array inside "for of" not working as intended

Tags: javascript

My program is getting a list of items (a string that is split) and grouping them by the number of `"-"` in the start of every phrase, putting them in different levels inside the variable `quantityCreatedArray`,

Since this number is changed in every click of a button, I want to store every change in the variable `quantityCreatedArray`,

I'm doing this trying to push arrays inside an array using the method `Array.push()`,

This whole part is inside a `for of` structure that is needed for another part of my code (not important),

The problem is that the array `arrayUsed` (that have all arrays from the variable `quantityCreatedArray`) is returning an array with arrays that have the last change in the variable `quantityCreatedArray`...

Since I'm using the `push` method to put the arrays inside `arrayUsed`, I tried putting the variables directly in `arrayUsed` using a simple `for`, yet, the results are the same...

Below is some sample code for you to test

```js
menus = [
  "- LEVEL 1",
  "- - LEVEL1-1",
  "- - - LEVEL 1-1-1",
  "- - - LEVEL1-1-2",
  "- - - - LEVEL1-1-2-1",
  "- - - - - LEVEL 1-1-2-1-1",
  "- - - - LEVEL-1-2-2",
  "- - - LEVEL-1-3",
  "- LEVEL2"
];

var quantityCreatedArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var arrayUsed = [];

for (let item of menus) {
  let itemSplited = item.split(" ");
  let counter = 0;

  while (itemSplited[counter] == "-") {
    counter++;
  }

  for(let i1 = 0;i1<counter;i1++) {
    itemSplited.shift()
  }

  quantityCreatedArray[counter]++
  arrayUsed.push(quantityCreatedArray);
}

console.log(arrayUsed);
```

I expected a record of all changes in the variable `quantityCreatedArray` inside `arrayUsed`, but instead, I got just the last change in it.

Comment: You are pushing the same array multiple times into `arrayUsed`, as opposed to each being a distinct array.

Comment: Hi Scott, im using a "console.log(quantityCreatedArray)" before the push method and it returns a different array everytime, so I think they are distinct arrays (unless im doing something wrong...)

Comment: he refers to same instance.. try `arrayUsed.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(quantityCreatedArray)));`

Comment: You are *changing* `quantityCreatedArray`, not making new arrays.

Comment: Thanks guijob for the solution, it worked :D, also thanks Scott for pointing the error :p

Comment: for shallow copy you can use just `arrayUsed.push( quantityCreatedArray.slice() );` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value